# Why does my application stop?

Tags: android

I have no idea whats causing my app to crash, the logcat says its getting a fatal exception from MAIN, i don't really know what that means im pretty new to this stuff. What happens is the first activity loads fine but as soon as i press the button to load the second activity is stops. Sorry if its a too long question or already been asked, i've tried a lot of things posted in previously asked questions.

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".QuizActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:exported="false"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">

            </category>                
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>    
    </activity>

</application>
```

first activity

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
Button quizButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_mainmenu);

    quizButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.launchQuiz);

    quizButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v.getId() == quizButton.getId()) {
                Intent launchQuizActivity = new Intent(MainMenu.this, QuizActivity.class);
                MainMenu.this.startActivity(launchQuizActivity);

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

and heres the second one:

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {

Intent returnHome = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, matt.apps.quiz.MainMenu.class);

String questions[] = {"What month is it?","What OS is this?" };
String lChoices[] = {"July","IOS"};
String cChoices[] = {"August","Android"};
String rChoices[] = {"October", "Windows?"};
int answers[] = {R.id.lButton,R.id.cButton };

boolean correct = false;
int numCorrect = 0;
int numWrong = 0;
int btnClicked;
int i = -1;
int t = 0;

Button lButton;
Button cButton;
Button rButton;
Button nextButton;
TextView questionTV;
TextView greetingTV;



public boolean getCorrect(int id) {
    if (id == answers[i]) {
        correct = true;
    } else {
    correct = false;
    }
    return correct;
}

OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
    //TODO change to method to handle answers
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    btnClicked = v.getId();

                    if (btnClicked == R.id.nextButton) { // next button

                        i += 1;

                        if (i <= questions.length) {
                        questionTV.setText(questions[i]);
                        lButton.setText(lChoices[i]);
                        cButton.setText(cChoices[i]);
                        rButton.setText(rChoices[i]);
                        nextButton.setText("Next question");
                        } else {
                            questionTV.setText("You got " + numCorrect + " right and " + numWrong + " wrong.");
                            lButton.setText("");
                            cButton.setText("");
                            rButton.setText("");
                        } // end of next button 

                    } else { // answer buttons
                    if (i > -1) { 
                        if (i <= questions.length) {
                    if (getCorrect(btnClicked) == true) {
                        numCorrect += 1;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        numWrong += 1;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            } 
        }// end of answer buttons
                }   
            };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    greetingTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.greetingTV);
    questionTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionTV);
    lButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lButton);
    cButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cButton);
    rButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rButton);
    nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

    //set on click listeners for buttons      


        questionTV.setText("Please click the start button to begin.");
        nextButton.setText("Start");

}
}
```

Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  620): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{matt.apps.quiz/matt.apps.quiz.QuizActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
E/AndroidRuntime(  620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
E/AndroidRuntime(  620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(  620):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
```

Comment: v.getId() == quizButton.getId(), I guess you need a v == quizButton, but a log would help

Comment: There is no need to do if (v.getId() == quizButton.getId()) { , since you've only set this OnClickHandler on your quizButton ... i.e. no other button clicks will get you here.  Anyhow, this won't solve your crash.  Use 'adb logcat' to get a log dump, the stack trace will point you to your crash.

Comment: Alright ill post a log after my conditioning, and i tried what you posted siddharth and it didn't work :/

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the onclick event, does it get called when you push the button? If you put a breakpoint in the oncreate method of the next view, does it get called?

Comment: yeah csmith i changed that lol

Comment: what on earth does the logcat say Matthagan.

Comment: You read it since you said FATAL.  So why not share the next few lines with us?

Comment: I'm docking a point for not posting the log.  I think you have read it since you must have or you would not have mentioned FATAL which only is seen in the log.

Comment: You might not realize it but its more important to learn how to debug the when you reach this point than anything else.  Share the log!

Comment: btw, the +5 on Pavel Dudkas comment means 5 people agree that you should share the log.

Comment: @CodeDroid All five of you comments in within those ten minutes are essentially asking the author for the logcat, which as you noticed Pavel has already done. There is no need to repeat the same comment.

Comment: Sorry guys I just had lacrosse conditioning, but i added the logcat finally.

Comment: just use startActivity(launchQuizActivity); and use this line inside onCreate method `Intent returnHome = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, matt.apps.quiz.MainMenu.class);`

Answer (score 1):

Well Matthagan, the LogCat has the fatal exception.  Its in Red. Now what you want to do is first of all always print at least the first 4 lines after fatal so people know what you got.  If you want to see the exact spot and your in eclipse, goto the first line below fatal that contains YOUR PACKAGE NAME.  Click on this line an it will take you to the exact spot.

Here is what it could be.

1) quizButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.launchQuiz);  returns null so you get a null pointer exception.  This could occur becase launchQuiz is is not properly definied the your layout.

2) You might not have a height and width specified for an element in the layout.

Comment: your crash is more likely in the QuizActivity OnCreate, likely for one of the reasons outlined here by Code Droid

Comment: Just added the logcat, and ill change those things around to see if anything works, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You have a NullPointer (it says so at the end of the first line after FATAL EXCEPTION in your logcat). Just trace to where the stacktrace mentions your package name (right now it's only showing up to android.app.ActivityThread) - just like reading a Java stack trace.